Portfolio quantity optimization violates DCP rules in CVXPY
I need to estimate the optimal quantity of individual stocks in a portfolio based on the daily net value fluctuations of the portfolio (known), where some of the stock quantity are known (corresponding to given_ids), and some stock quantity information is unknown (guess_ids), and the daily return rates of every individual stocks are known.
It is easy for us to estimate the optimal weight for each individual stock, but the issue lies in that we need to estimate the quantity for each stock.
Now the problem arises: if we want to satisfy the matching of known quantity information in the quantity estimation while also making the weights based on the estimated positions minimize the tracking error of the target return rate, the program will throw a constraint error that program does not follow the DCP rules.
Here below is the main code of my processing procedure, the error lies in the second constraint, which is designed to match the known stock position information.
        # stock number
        num = len(total_ids)
        resid_num = len(resid_holdings)
        given_num = num - resid_num

        # stocks with unknown holdings
        guess_holdings = cp.Variable(resid_num, nonneg=True)  # quantity
        guess_close = close_df.loc[est_date, resid_ids]  # price
        guess_value = cp.multiply(guess_holdings, guess_close) # holding value

        # stocks with known holdings
        given_holdings = select_short_data.set_index('code')['est_holdings']  # 转变为已知信息
        given_close = close_df.loc[est_date, given_ids]
        given_value = given_holdings.mul(given_close)  

        # total holding value 
        total_guess_value = cp.sum(guess_value) + given_value.sum()

        # daily stock return rate
        resid_stock_pct = total_stock_pct.loc[est_date, resid_ids].fillna(0)
        given_stock_pct = total_stock_pct.loc[est_date, given_ids].fillna(0)


        w_r = cp.Variable(resid_num, nonneg=True) 
        w_g = cp.Variable(given_num, nonneg=True)  

        # tracking error objective function
        track_error = target_rets - resid_stock_pct.values @ w_r - given_stock_pct.values @ w_g
        # holding value deviation constraint
        # value_change = cp.multiply(total_guess_value, w_g) - given_value  
        total_error = cp.norm(track_error, 2) 

        constraints = []
        constraints += [cp.sum(w_r) + cp.sum(w_g) == 1]  
        constraints += [cp.multiply(total_guess_value, w_g) == given_value.values]  # **This constraint does not follow DCP rules**
        constraints += [guess_holdings >= 0]  
        constraints += [w_r >= 0, w_r <= 0.1, w_g >= 0]  
        # constraints += [refer_w - w_r <= 0.00005, w_r - refer_w <= 0.00005]

        objective_func = cp.Minimize(total_error)
        prob = cp.Problem(objective_func, constraints=constraints)
        prob.solve(solver=cp.ECOS, verbose=False, **solver_options, qcp=True)
        print('-->', prob.status)
        resid_opt_w = pd.Series(data=w_r.value.round(6), index=resid_ids)
        given_w = pd.Series(data=w_g.value.round(6), index=given_ids)


